# Embedded Python Via Yocto

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, yocto

I have come across while doing code to raspberrypi 3+ with Yocto. The Python code is absolutely unreliable. I can write Python3 script that runs beautifully Even when there is a Bug. No error messages it just runs over. It makes debugging Python quite hard. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question lacks details that would make it answerable. Consider adding an example of code that fails with an explanation of how exactly it fails.

Comment: Logging functions are provided by BitBake and can be used in Python Script code. Functions are `bb.fatal`, `bb.error`, `bb.warn`, `bb.note`, `bb.plain` and `bb.debug`